# PL/SQL: Can I use procedure inputs directly in the select statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I was trying to refactor a piece of code. We do a similar select on a table and a view and I wanted to export the select in a procedure and use the table name as an input parameter. So for example:

```
procedure show_table (
  i_table_name varchar2
)
is
begin
  for c in (
    select *
    from i_table_name
  ) loop
    ...
  end loop;
end;
```

But PL/SQL thinks i_table_name is a literal name (throws PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist). Is there a way to evaluate the contents of the variable? I guess I can do an execute immediate but I would rather not :)

Cheers.

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184015/dynamic-query-in-oracle-procedure-using-cursor

Comment: If you don't want to declare the cursor dynamically, you could declare two cursors and choose which to open based on the parameter value; depends if you're worried about duplication of the select, or duplication of the code within the loop?

Comment: @AlexPoole I wanted to avoid duplication code within the loop, since the select is going to be different anyway.

Comment: @GunjanShakya I guess I'll have to go with a dynamic query. Thanks both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible approach is to use a ref cursor (this assumes that your view has *exactly* the same columns as the table):

```
create table test_tab(pk number, value varchar2(30));
insert into test_tab values (1, 'hello');
create view test_view as select pk, value || '_view' as value from test_tab;

declare
  procedure show_table(i_table_name varchar2) is
    cur sys_refcursor;  
    rec test_tab%rowtype;
  begin
    open cur for 'select * from ' || i_table_name;
    loop
      fetch cur into rec;
      exit when cur%notfound;
      dbms_output.put_line(rec.pk ||' ' || rec.value);
    end loop;
  end;
begin
  show_table('TEST_TAB');
  show_table('TEST_VIEW');
end;
```

Comment: I guess I cannot avoid dynamic queries as far as I can tell. Thanks for the help :)